# Raster from XYZ with values as factors

Tags: r, dataframe, raster

I want to create a raster from a data frame. The column from which I want to create the raster is a character. I converted it as factor, but still this  does not work. One month ago it has created a raster from factor values, but it seems doesn't work anymore, idk.

```
  tabf$class <- factor(tabf$class)
  
  kopen <- rasterFromXYZ(cbind(tabf[,1:2],tabf[,"class"]))
  
  kopen[] <-  factor(tabf$class)
```

the head of the data frame looks like :

```
     x    y T_w.m T_c.m T_avg P_tot P_wint P_summ P_d.m P_d.m.summ P_d.m.wint P_w.m P_w.m.summ P_w.m.wint T_4th_w.m class
63 26.3 48.4  20.3  -3.2   9.0 522.1  152.2  369.8  16.3       37.2       16.3 104.0      104.0       36.6      15.2   Dfb
64 26.4 48.4  20.5  -3.1   9.1 523.3  155.8  367.4  16.5       37.8       16.5 102.2      102.2       37.3      15.4   Dfb
65 26.5 48.4  20.7  -2.9   9.3 521.4  157.9  363.5  17.0       37.7       17.0 100.9      100.9       37.2      15.6   Cfb
66 26.6 48.4  20.8  -2.9   9.4 519.7  159.5  360.2  16.9       37.8       16.9 100.8      100.8       38.0      15.7   Cfb
67 26.7 48.4  20.8  -3.0   9.4 522.5  164.1  358.4  17.7       38.8       17.7 100.1      100.1       39.0      15.6   Cfb
68 26.8 48.4  20.6  -3.1   9.2 531.5  167.0  364.6  17.9       39.6       17.9 102.0      102.0       39.7      15.5   Dfb
```

Comment: Hi @Alex.V The function `rasterFromXYZ()` expects values (i.e. numbers). Your `tabf$class` column is not of class `numeric` but of class `character`. That's why it doesn't work.

Comment: It's strange. Two months ago it worked from factor values.